# Django List Based Off Previous List

Tags: python, django

I am trying to make a dynamic list of choices. That is, the choices change based on a previous answer. For example, if `country = ["USA", "Canada", "Mexico"]`, then click "USA" will generate a list with the 50 US States, `state = ["Alabama", "Alaska"]`. I tried to do an if statement, however, that did not seem to work. I am not sure what the best option for this is.

```
class Property(models.Model):
    address = CharField(max_length = 200)
    city = CharField(max_length = 200)

    COUNTRY_LIST = [
        ("USA", "United States"),
        ("CAN", "Canada")
    ]
    country = CharField(max_length = 3, choices = COUNTRY_LIST)

    USA_STATE_LIST = [
        ("AL", "Alabama"),
        ("AK", "Alaska"),
        ("AZ", "Arizona")
    ]
    CAN_STATE_LIST = [
        ("AL", "Alberta"),
        ("BC", "British Columbia")
    ]
    state = CharField(max_length = 2, choices = ?)
```

Comment: I would say to put the entries in as a separate table called country in the database and then use a foreign key country_id to another table states. So you can search for country_id in states table.

Comment: Thanks, I cannot believe I didn't think of that.

Answer (score 1):

I think we may need to rethink  your model.

state

```
  class State(models.Model)
          name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

country

```
   class Country(models.Model)
          name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

and use this in property model

```
class Property(models.Model):
    address = CharField(max_length = 200)
    city = CharField(max_length = 200) 
    country = models.ForeignKey(Country,on_delete=Bla)
    state = models.ForeignKey(State,on_delete=Bla)
```